# How to structure MySQL database tables for users and how to handle adding/removing permissions?

Tags: mysql, permissions, php, role

I am making a database structure for users, who can become part of a group, and within that group the admin of the group can assign as many permissions to a user as they would like.
This part seems easy. I have 4 tables:

```
 USERS           GROUPS             PERMISSIONS      PERMISSIONS_GROUPS
-------  ---------------------    --------------    -------------------
| UID |  | GID | UID(creator) |   | PID | NAME |    | UID | GID | PID |
```

I think this is the best way to handle this. I have a few questions about how to handle permissions for the creator of the group, and how to handle permissions if I were to delete a permission or add a permission.
For instance, when a user makes a group. Do I query all of the permissions and in a `while` loop insert a `PERMISSIONS_GROUPS` record for every row in the `permissions` table? If I add a new permission, do I have to query every `UID` from the `GROUPS` table and run a `while` loop to insert the new permission into `PERMISSIONS_GROUPS`? I just want to make sure I am not missing something simple here. For structure/scripting I am using `MySQL` and `PHP`.

Comment: All creators will have same permissions? Or creator permission changes with each group?

Comment: If all creators have same permissions then store that as user meta like key 'creator_permissions', value '1,5,7,8,9,10' , you can store that as stringify or comma separated values.

Comment: You could also create another table to store creator permissions. This will also allow you to set different permissions for each group creator.

Answer (score 1):

A sketch for an alternative approach would be:

```
-- supertype for user / group, it is not clear from your post what 
-- an appropriate name would be, so I'll just use `x`. each x is of a 
-- certain type.

CREATE TABLE x_types
( x_type CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
, -- maybe add a description 
);

INSERT INTO x_types (x_type) VALUES ('u'), ('g');
 

CREATE TABLE x
( xid ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, x_type CHAR(1) NOT NULL
, UNIQUE (x_type, xid)
-- common attributes for user / group
...
);   


CREATE TABLE users 
( uid ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
, x_type CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'u' NOT NULL
-- user specific attributes
, ...
, CHECK (x_type = 'u') -- does not work in previous version of MySQL
, FOREIGN KEY (x_type, uid) REFERENCES x (x_type, xid)  
);

CREATE TABLE groups 
( gid ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
, x_type CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'u' NOT NULL 
-- group specific attributes
, group_creator ... NOT NULL
, ...
, CHECK (x_type = 'u') -- does not work in previous version of MySQL
, FOREIGN KEY (x_type, gid) REFERENCES x (x_type, xid)
, FOREIGN KEY (group_creator) REFERENCES users (uid)  
);

-- a relationship between supertype and permission
CREATE TABLE x_permissions
( xid ... NOT NULL
, pid ... NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (xid, pid)
, FOREIGN KEY (xid) REFERENCES x (xid)
, FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES permissions (pid)
);

-- group membership for users 
CREATE TABLE group_users
( gid ... NOT NULL REFERENCES groups (gid)
, uid ... NOT NULL REFERENCES users (uid)
, PRIMARY KEY (gid, uid) 
);
```

This may suit your needs, but it is hard to tell without knowing the exact business rules. Identifiers are of course just bogus and need to be adjusted.